# How to install nvm in mac?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am unable to install nvm in my mac. I have installed node and it's running perfectly fine but unable to install nvm on my system. while checking node version it showing :

`node -v v21.3.0`

but when i try to check nvm version it gives me error :

`nvm -v zsh: command not found: nvm`

when i try to install nvm it gives me error :

`brew install nvm`

Warning: nvm 0.39.5 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 0.39.5, run:
brew reinstall nvm

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the warning which you added in your question, I surmise that `nvm` is installed on your machine but may not have been setup properly. There are few steps to set it up. You can check which one you missed and fix that up.

1. You'll need to create a `.nvm` directory to store the related files.

   ```bash
    mkdir ~/.nvm # you can create it at any place but generally home is best place.
   ```
2. Add `nvm` configuration in `.zshrc` file to set up the environment variables and source the nvm script:

   ```bash
   export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This 
   loads nvm
   [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . 
   "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
   ```
3. Save and close the editor(which you used for updating your `.zshrc`) and restart your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` to apply the changes.

These steps generally set up the `nvm` on `MAC`. You can check which steps you have missed.